# Kotlin: add an interface to guice-injected dependencies such that we could mock them just for unit test purposes?

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito, guice, apache-storm

I have a storm topology that uses guice to inject various dependencies in the bolts. The dependencies are not constructer injected because of storm serialization/deserialization issues. We pass a guice `injector` object to the bolt constructor and use it in the bolt's `prepare` method to field inject the dependencies (non-ideal, I know, but don't know a better scenario for now).

```
class MyBolt(val injector: Injector) : AbstractRichBolt() {
   @Inject
   @Transient
   private lateinit var myController: MyController
   ...
   override fun prepare(...) {
       this.injector.injectMembers(this)
   }
   override fun execute(input: Tuple) {
       // use myController in our logic here
   }
}
```

I'm writing unit tests for the bolt with a test guice module such that I can inject mock dependencies for things like database controllers, etc. To do that, I need to bind the controller class to a mocked class:

```
bind(MyController::class.java).toInstance(MockController())
```

However, to make this work, I have to make `MockController` inherit from the same interface/super class as `MyController`. What I am not sure about is if this is a good practice to add an interface to `MyController` just for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has a feature that allows you to implement a function as an interface. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type.

```
class MyController : (Int) -> String {
    override fun invoke(in: Int) : String = "Real Logic"
}
```

Then make a test double with the behavior you want in your tests

```
class StubMyController : (Int) -> String {
    override fun invoke(in: Int) : String = "Test Logic"
}
```

Then inject the test double using your injector

```
bind(MyController::class.java).toInstance(StubMyController())
```

You can only do this once for a class. I have used this feature instead of extra interfaces or adding open to the class. It believe it very much encourages SOLID principles. There's a lot more to them, but having only one public method on a class certainly can help keep one focused on SOLID.

I understand the desire to group related methods into a single class, but with Kotlin you can have the best of both. You can have very simple classes with one public method, but group these related classes into a single file. It is difficult to explain why this can help, but it can really make testing easier and more readable.

You can also use mockk https://mockk.io/ to mock the dependencies directly.

Comment: I don't know how the function as interface approach would look like. Can you show me how it looks like in my example?

Comment: Also `MyController` has a few methods that I need to mock. So if I can only do it once, it may not meet my needs?

Comment: I've read briefly the documentation for `mockK` and it looks real interesting. However, all the examples I saw in the doc were mocking the object directly, instead of mocking an indirect object that is derived from a guice injector.